# get HTML page sources from multiple sites

Tags: c#, html, winforms

There several websites that use AJAX to update the contents periodically and I would like to monitor them. That's why it is necessary to keep **multiple** webpage windows **always open** and to grab page sources periodically.

I am searching for an approach for getting HTML sources from these webpages! Could you recommend something? I need it for statistical analysis.

Here are my thoughts so far:

1. approach. Opening separate Chrome windows manually. Using Handles to find the window. The problem is that it is nearly impossible to grab the HTML of the webpage.. (except the  rich text)
2. Approach. writing an extension for Chrome/Firefox and a C# program. Program will send requests to extension and the extension will return HTML contents of the webpage. That's the theory. Google didn't put my hopes high so I am not sure if that is possible...
3. Approach. The most realistic one. Using the embed browser such as CefSharp, Awesomium, etc.. But as I mentioned - they have to support multiple opened windows! Any problems here?

So, these are my thought after hours of study..
Personally I would love to implement approach 2 because it is the most awesome.. but others will do too. What would be the easiest and most bulletproof?

Additionaly I would love a feature to do some input operations in these windows. ex: Login/navigate.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If IE browser is an option, look at implementing a managed add-on that will allow you to hook into notifications when document is loaded, access to live DOM of the document, possibly notifications when DOM changes, and so on.  The same can be done in FF/Chrome.  With IE, look into `IObjectWithSite` COM interface.  [This article seems to be a decent tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19971/How-to-attach-to-Browser-Helper-Object-BHO-with-C), though I'm not vouching for its accuracy.